# Can I execute an Application that uses dyanmic lib loading if libraries aren't present?

Tags: linker, embedded-linux

I have a linux application that runs on two different file systems. 1 filesystem has shared libs that I link against (i.e. -lssl), the other doesn't (because its too big to add).

When using the smaller filesystem without the libssl.so present, the app wont execute because it can't dynamically link.

If i was going to go through the process of dynamically loading the lssl when i want to use it, does the application still need to the so just to execute? Even if no calls to libssl are ever made?

Comment: *"...it can't dynamically link because it cant dynamically link."* -- Maybe I should start explaining things this way too.  It's so much faster to write and it's guaranteed to be  accurate!

Comment: sorry - edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You can load the library manually using dlopen() and dlclose()

Redesigning your app to use dlopen and dlclose to access the ssl library  functions vs linking, will allow usage of the ssl functions *only* when it is present. With this approach you can have single build that allows you to avoid having to link to the ssl library (and always require its presence at runtime).

Check out here: [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

Comment: *"You can load the library manually..."* -- Load from where? Your "answer" ignores the fact that the shared object is not stored locally.  How would these functions even help the OP solve the problem? Add them into an application that cannot execute because the dynamic linker fails?

Comment: Updated response to clarify the ability to have a single build to support when the ssl library is present and when it is not. @sawdust please revisit the -1.